# When is $E(X-\mu)^2 \ne E(X^2)-\mu^2$?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics, random-variables

Consider the probability density function
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{18}, \quad x \in [0,18]$$
Find $E(x)$ and $Var(x)$.

---

**Solution**:

a.)
\begin{align*}
E(x)
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) dx \\
&=\int_{0}^{18} x \left(\frac{x}{18}\right) dx \\
&=\frac{1}{18} \int_0^{18} x^2 dx \\
&=108
\end{align*}

b.)

**Method 1:**
\begin{align*}
Var(x)
&=E(x-\mu)^2 \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x-\mu) f(x) dx \\
&=\int_{0}^{18} (x-108)^2 \left(\frac{x}{18}\right) dx \\
&=83106
\end{align*}

**Method 2:**
\begin{align*}
Var(x)
&=E(x^2)-\mu^2 \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 f(x) dx - (108)^2 \\
&=\int_{0}^{18} x^2 \left(\frac{x}{18}\right) dx - (108)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{18}\int_{0}^{18} x^3 dx - (108)^2\\
&=-10206
\end{align*}

Clearly the second method is wrong, since a variance cannot be negative. But I cannot find the error. Can someone explain why the two methods yield different values? Is it not always the case that  $E(X-\mu)^2 \ne E(X^2)-\mu^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add one further dimension of insight, I want to point out that the reason the non-normalized density matters is a little subtle. The other answers are right, but it’s not super obvious why. The usual proof (using linearity of expectation) that your two expressions for the variance are equal does not seem to rely on normalization, after all.

In particular, we have

$$E[(X-\mu)^2]=E[X^2-2\mu X+\mu^2]=E[X^2]-2\mu E[X]+E[\mu^2]=E[X^2]-2\mu^2+E[\mu^2]$$

and all this goes through regardless of whether the density is normalized. The normalization matters only for the last step: equating $E[\mu^2]$ with $\mu^2$. These won’t agree unless the density is normalized.

Comment: good insight! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your error is simply the fact that $f(x)$ does not define a probability density function, i.e., your $f(x)$ does not satisfy $$\int_0^{18} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 1.$$

Comment: Wow, good catch! This came from a Cengage online homework of one of my students -- associated with the book "Mathematical Applications for the Management, Life, and Social Sciences" by Harshbarger & Reynolds. I am assuming the density is supposed to be $f(x)=1/18$.

Comment: no worries! You are welcome!

Comment: @Mathemanic Or $x/9$, or maybe it's meant to have support $[-18,\,18]$ or $[0,\,36]$. This is why typos are dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

The probability density function integrates to 9 in the interval given, that is why it does not work.

Comment: Great catch! This problem came from a Cengage online homework of one of my students, associated with the book "Mathematical Applications for the Management, Life, and Social Sciences" by Harshbarger & Reynolds. I am assuming the density is supposed to be $f(x)=1/18$. Thanks for the answer. ;)

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck!